# ORACLE- query regarding TIMESTAMP

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

```
select flightdate from flight;
```

```
FLIGHTDATE

01-DEC-12 10.09.01.340000 AM
02-DEC-12 10.09.01.340000 AM
02-DEC-12 10.09.01.340000 AM
03-DEC-12 10.09.01.340000 AM
05-DEC-12 10.09.01.340000 AM
03-DEC-12 10.09.01.340000 AM
04-DEC-12 10.09.01.340000 AM
06-DEC-12 10.09.01.340000 AM
```

Now I want to get the flightdate > 03-DEC-12

I have written the query as

```
select flightdate from flight where flightdate>'03-DEC-12'
```

output:

```
03-DEC-12 10.09.01.340000 AM
05-DEC-12 10.09.01.340000 AM
03-DEC-12 10.09.01.340000 AM
04-DEC-12 10.09.01.340000 AM
06-DEC-12 10.09.01.340000 AM
```

I am even getting the 03-DEC-12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting events from the December 3rd because `03-DEC-12` gets interpreted as `2012-12-03T00:00:00` and an event 10 hours after midnight does match.

If you want events starting the following day, use

```
SELECT *
FROM flight 
WHERE FLIGHTDATE >= DATE '2012-12-04'
-- or FLIGHTDATE >= (DATE '2012-12-03') + 1
```

You could also truncate the datetime to a date using the [`TRUNC` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm), but this may make the query non-sargable:

```
SELECT *
FROM flight
WHERE TRUNC(FLIGHTDATE) > TO_DATE('03-DEC-12', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

Comment: Thank you.can u plz explain me what the trunc in trunc(flightdate) do

Comment: @Bharath - Mitch has included a link to the documentation for `trunc`, which explains clearly what ti's doing.

Answer (score 0):

- Here your Flightdate column contains time stamp(03-DEC-12 10.09.01.340000).
- In where clause you provided flightdate>'03-DEC-12'.
- Oracle treated the date you supplied as flightdate>'03-DEC-12 00.00.00.000'
- So when ever you deal with date its always better to use TO_DATE() function.